# Как переделать команду rm для использования в Windows?

Tags: linux, windows, docker, командная-строка

Я столкнулся с проблемой конфигурационного файла, создаваемого в Cypress для подключения отчетов. Соответствующий мануал на сайте Cypress https://docs.cypress.io/guides/tooling/reporters#Examples  предлагает использовать команду

````
```rm cypress/results/* || true```
````

которая в Windows не работает. Как ее можно переделать, и что в данном случае означает "или true"? Более того, в дальнейшем данный конфигурационный файл в составе тестового проекта необбходимо будет поместить в Docker контейнер, который использует ядро операционной системы Linux. Будет ли, в таком случае, сконвертированная под Windows команда работать там? Не может ли кто-нибудь помочь мне разобраться во всех этих перепетиях и найти правильное решение?

Comment: Если всё равно в докере запускать, то зачем заморачиваться переделкой под Винду? Поставьте докер и запускайте сразу в нём

Comment: Собственно в Докере и состоит вся проблема. Я только приступил к его изучению и, в данном случае, хотел сранить работу тестов под виндой и в Докере.

Comment: баш скрипты это просто способ выполнять команды, доступные на конечной машине. Даже в рамках одной ос набор команд зависит от ее сборки. Например alpine образы в Docker Hub имеет весьма ограниченный набор утилит. Если кроссплатформенность это обязательный пункт, рассмотрите вариант использовать более высокоуровневый скриптовый язык. Например Python.

Comment: Походу ребята в Cypress не умеют в shell, да.